# Get per day page hits count of users

Tags: php, drupal-7

I have site with thousands of user and logins each day. I need to track each page views of each user to generate a report. If a user 'A' visits a page 'P' today, a new entry `daycount` is added to the DB. If the same user 'A' visits the same page 'P' on same day, the `daycount` will increment by one. If a user 'A' visits  page 'P' tomorrow, a new entry `daycount` is added to the DB. The details needs to save is Page Title, User ID, Timestamp & daycount. Can any one share the code for this. I am using drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal core has Statistic module that keep logs of node, but doesn't store the user uid. For this drupal contributed module Node View Count will be helpful.

https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeviewcount

"Node View Count module allows to count node views. Unlike statistics module, this module records each view of node with user uid and timestamp. So now you can know how many times a user viewed node by day, week, month and etc."

Comment: Thanks Neha. I need to store the details of view pages and front page also. Which don't have any ID.